# I'm not seeing span tags in DOM when adding them via javascript loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, dom

I am trying to target span tags by class name to change the color based on respective class, but I'm not seeing them in my DOM, all I see is the `<p>` tag. The text I'm adding to the span tags in my loop is working, but there are no span tags for me to target.

I'm expecting `<span>` tags to be nested in the `<p>` tag so I can target them to change the color.

Here's the code...

```
<p class="holder"></p>
```

```
const holder = document.querySelector('.holder');
const span = document.createElement('span');
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const html = document.querySelector('html');
const fizzBuzz = document.getElementsByClassName('.fizzBuzz');

html.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';


for(let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {        
        span.setAttribute('class', 'fizzBuzz');
        fizzBuzz.style.color = 'brown';
        span.textContent = 'FizzBuzz, ';
        holder.appendChild(span);

    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
        span.setAttribute('class', 'buzz');
        span.textContent = 'Buzz, ';
        holder.appendChild(span);

    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        span.setAttribute('class', 'fizz');
        span.textContent = 'Fizz, ';
        holder.appendChild(span);

    } else {
        holder.textContent += `${i}, `;
        holder.style.color = 'white';
    }

    if (i === 100) {
        holder.textContent = holder.textContent.slice(holder.textContent, holder.textContent.length - 2);
        holder.textContent += '.';
    }

}

body.appendChild(holder);
```

Also, this is my first question and I'm new to coding, so let me know how I can improve my question or code, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> holder.textContent += '.';
> ```

Assigning a string to `textContent` erases the existing content of the element, including the span element you added.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    x.textContent += " content";
}, 500);
```

```css
span { background: blue }
```

```html
<div id="x"><span>Example</span></div>
```

Instead, [create a text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) and append it like you append the span.

---

Aside: You only create one span and then repeatedly modify and move it. You probably want to create multiple span elements instead.

Comment: I didn't realize it erased the content, but that makes sense, thank you. So you suggest I create 3 different spans for the 3 words to target the color with, and use createTextNode instead of textContent... with the spans wrapping the text nodes?

Now that I realize I only was making one span and moving it, wouldn't creating three spans for all the words only make 3 and move them leading to the same problem as before?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: No, not three spans. Everywhere you currently set the class attribute on  the span you should first create a new span.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up taking a completely different approach and it worked. I looped through an empty array to add 1-100, then defined a function to replace the numbers with a span wrapping the words with the respective words and class on them. I then ran a forEach on the array to replace them, made the completed array a string, made the innerHTML on my paragraph the string, and looped through my querySelectorAll arrays to change their colors. Not sure if that's the best way to do it, but it worked lol...

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the  tags are not visible in the DOM is because you are using the same instance of the  element in the entire loop. Instead, you should create a new instance of the  element inside the loop so that a new  tag is created for each iteration.

Here's the updated code:

```
const holder = document.querySelector('.holder');
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const html = document.querySelector('html');

html.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';

for(let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    
    const span = document.createElement('span');

    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {        
        span.setAttribute('class', 'fizzBuzz');
        span.style.color = 'brown';
        span.textContent = 'FizzBuzz, ';
        holder.appendChild(span);

    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
        span.setAttribute('class', 'buzz');
        span.textContent = 'Buzz, ';
        holder.appendChild(span);

    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        span.setAttribute('class', 'fizz');
        span.textContent = 'Fizz, ';
        holder.appendChild(span);

    } else {
        holder.textContent += `${i}, `;
        holder.style.color = 'white';
    }

    if (i === 100) {
        holder.textContent = holder.textContent.slice(holder.textContent, holder.textContent.length - 2);
        holder.textContent += '.';
    }

}

body.appendChild(holder);
```